# Cos'è uno "sgabello trampolo"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi,  ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Entro nel pub che lui è già lí, seduto su uno degli *sgabelli trampolo* al banco. Ha davanti un boccale pieno, lo guarda. Non beve, non parla con nessuno.

Non capisco il significato di "sgabello trampolo" nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Probabilmente si riferisce a quegli sgabelli alti che ricordano i trampoli degli acrobati. Non è italiano “standard”: l'autrice sembra indulgere in neologismi o in dialettismi.

Comment: @egreg: Comunque, questa espressione appare anche in altri siti: http://www.chiaramicheli.it/page/3/, http://www.thrillermagazine.it/7450/capomillennio-racconto-di-natale, 
https://books.google.es/books?id=gVIxVsZRMC8C&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%22trampoli+degli+sgabelli%22&source=bl&ots=8akgczgaSO&sig=t-kLzi2_EAKohZld0VogrPRdclI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitwLen4_vJAhXGXBoKHfdwCyIQ6AEICzAA#v=onepage&q=%22trampoli%20degli%20sgabelli%22&f=false

Comment: Quello "classico" da pub credo sarebbe questo: [1](http://www.idfdesign.it/immagini/sgabelli-legno-rustici/715-sgabello-provenzale.jpg), ne ho visti molti anche così: [2](http://cdn-1.faidatemania.it/o/orig/come-realizzare-uno-sgabello_c11996dc24a8fc38061865774858f69f.jpg), ma sinceramente nemmeno io li ho mai sentiti chiamare così; "sgabello" di per sé (tra parentesi) sarebbe già corretto.

Comment: Nota anche che [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sgabello+trampolo%2Csgabelli+trampolo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) riporta zero risultati per "sgabello trampolo" e "sgabelli trampolo". Come per quell'altra domanda, direi che può essere decretato come un'invenzione dell'autrice (o al limite come un neologismo che ancora ha da prendere piede visto che lo hai trovato anche altrove).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trampoli sono quei bastoni con inserti per appoggiare i piedi e così poter essere più in alto. Si adoperavano in campagna per compiti di sorveglianza o per attraversare rii e acquitrini, ma ormai l'uso più comune è quello degli acrobati da circo o di strada.

Sedersi su certi sgabelli nei bar assomiglia ad arrampicarsi e stare sui trampoli, vista l'altezza: simili a questo, probabilmente.

[image]